# functional java 8 vs traditional java

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

I have been trying to get into functional programming with java for a few weeks now. I have created 2 functions below "validateFileFunctionally" and "validateFileRegularly" which perform same validations. First works in a functional way using predicates(we can assume Suppliers, Consumers also in here) while the second one works in traditional java ways.

In 2018 which way should I go.
And should I try to use functional programming everywhere in my code as being done in "validateFileFunctionally" or only with Streams?

```
public class Main {

private final String INVALID_FILE_NAME_LENGTH = "INVALID FILE NAME LENGTH";
private final String INVALID_FILE_EXTENSION = "INVALID FILE EXTENSION";
private final String INVALID_FILE_SIZE = "INVALID FILE SIZE";

public static void main(String... args) {
    File file = new File("text.pdf");
    Main main = new Main();
    main.validateFileFunctionally(file);
    main.validateFileRegularly(file);
}

private void validateFileFunctionally(File file) {
    BiPredicate<File, Integer> validateFileName = (f, maxLength) -> f.getName().length() < maxLength;
    BiPredicate<File, String> validateExtension = (f, type) -> f.getName().endsWith(type);
    BiPredicate<File, Integer> validateSize = (f, maxSize) -> f.length() <= maxSize;

    BiConsumer<Boolean, String> throwExceptionIfInvalid = (isValid, errorMessage) -> {
        if(!isValid) {
            throw new InvalidFileException(errorMessage);
        }
    };

    throwExceptionIfInvalid.accept(validateFileName.test(file, 20), INVALID_FILE_NAME_LENGTH);
    throwExceptionIfInvalid.accept(validateExtension.test(file, ".pdf") || validateExtension.test(file, ".csv"), INVALID_FILE_EXTENSION);
    throwExceptionIfInvalid.accept(validateSize.test(file, 20), INVALID_FILE_SIZE);
}

private void validateFileRegularly(File file) {
    if (file.getName().length() > 20) {
        throw new InvalidFileException("INVALID FILE NAME LENGTH");
    } else if (!file.getName().endsWith(".pdf") && !file.getName().endsWith(".csv")) {
        throw new InvalidFileException("INVALID FILE NAME LENGTH");
    } else if (file.length() > 20) {
        throw new InvalidFileException("INVALID FILE NAME LENGTH");
    }
}

class InvalidFileException extends RuntimeException {
    public InvalidFileException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted, this isn't a particularly great question, but it is valid, as the selected answer by @Michael Berry is a useful response to those who are trying to understand when NOT to use functional Java 8.

Comment: The question should have been posted at StackExchange CodeReviews (I did not downvote, but I would have supported it). I know examples where functional programming is less readable than imperative, but this example is just poorly coded. Not only the method `validateFileFunctionally` but also the call (if it was called with functions in mind, it would not look this way).

Comment: @CoronA: thanks for your comments.
you can assume these 2 methods present in a service/ component and then being used by other parts of the application for example in a controller to validate to the uploaded file. can you please tell how you would have written it functionally and imperatively also.

Comment: @RohitJain: Your design is that you have a service that throws an exception. One way to make it functional would be to have a stream of files, filtering out the invalid ones (or transforming them to error objects and handling them afterwards). One indicator that you are not truely functional is that the methods `validateXXX` do not return anything. That means they rely on side effects. Post your example on StackExchange Code Reviews if you want to know how to do it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dah, this is a pet peeve of mine I'm afraid. Don't try to cram in functional stuff everywhere just because it's the latest new / cool thing - that just makes your code hard to read and unconventional. The Java 8 functional libraries are just another tool you have available that allow you to write cleaner, more concise code in a number of cases. You certainly shouldn't aim to use them exclusively.

Take your case as an example - the chained if statements still might not be the best way of achieving the above, but I can look at that and know near enough exactly what's going on in a few seconds.

Meanwhile, the functional example is just - rather odd. It's longer, less obvious as to what's going on, and offers no real advantage. I can't see a single case for using it as written in this example.

Comment: This is not the "functional equivalent"... This is another imperative version using functional language features. The functional equivalent would probably involve using the `Validation` applicative functor or the `Either` monad depending on the usecase and thereby become a lot more concise and readable.

Answer (score 0):

You should be applying Functional Programming wherever it makes sense, and stay away from bold statements like:

- `"I should try to use FP everywhere in my code"`
- `"I should code only with Streams"`

However, keep in mind that **this example is not functional at all** - `validateFileFunctionally` is just an enterprise-grade version of `validateFileRegularly`

Simply put, you took an imperative piece of code and rewrote it by wrapping it into FP infrastructure which is not what FP is about.

FP is about removing runtime uncertainty by building code from small and predictable building blocks/values, and not by putting lambda expressions wherever possible.

In your example, one could achieve this by abandoning exception handling and representing validation result as a value:

```
private Result validateFileRegularly(File file) {
    if (file.getName().length() > 20) {
        return Result.failed("INVALID FILE NAME LENGTH");
    } else if (!file.getName().endsWith(".pdf") && !file.getName().endsWith(".csv")) {
        return Result.failed("INVALID FILE NAME LENGTH");
    } else if (file.length() > 20) {
        return Result.failed("INVALID FILE NAME LENGTH");
    }

    return Result.ok();
}
```

Naturally, one could use the more sophisticated syntax for that, or a more sophisticated applicative-based validation API, but essentially that's what's all about.